# Import custom css stylesheet for each page with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Is there a way to import a different stylesheet for each page, without mixing the classes?

For example, for index.html to have style.css, for about.html how would I load a about.css into it?

This is my angular code:

```
    // create module
var heykatapp = angular.module('heykatapp', ['ngRoute']);

// routes configuration 
heykatapp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    // home page
        .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    // about page
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
        controller: 'aboutController'
    })

    // contact page
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
        controller: 'contactController'
    });
});

heykatapp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {});
heykatapp.controller('aboutController', function ($scope) {});
heykatapp.controller('contactController', function ($scope) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just insert the scripts in each view

contact.html with this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contact.css">
```

index.html with this another css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
```